# protractor how to detect md-progress-circular and wait for it to close

Tags: protractor

I have a `md-progress-circular` component on my web page with animation which comes up on every click since data is being fetched from backend for most of calls, my script fails because response time for each call is different and circular loader stays on screen for random time and script fails with following error

```
Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1442, 472). Other element would receive the click: 
<div id="blockUiBackdrop" ng-show="blockingUI" aria-hidden="false" class="ng-animate ng-hide-animate ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active" data-ng-animate="2">...</div>
      (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the mode of the `md-progress-circular` component of your webPage

Case 1: Determinate - This is when you know the status of the back-ground operation and there is a `value` attribute which lets you know when the operation is complete

Example:

`<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="34" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="progressbar" class="ng-isolate-scope" aria-valuenow="34" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></md-progress-circular>`

You can add a `browser.wait()` here to check for the attribute value to equal `aria-valuemax`

Case 2: Indeterminate - This is when you don't know whats happening behind the scenes and you need to check for the invisibility of the element

Example:

`<md-progress-circular ng-disabled="!vm.activated" class="md-hue-2 ng-isolate-scope _md-progress-circular-disabled" md-diameter="20px" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="progressbar" md-mode="indeterminate" aria-disabled="true" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" disabled="disabled">
</md-progress-circular>`

In such cases there are two options

1.Identify the ng-model value which determines the visibility of the component like in this case - `vm.activated` and access the scope and wait for the value change

2.do a `browser.wait()` on `invisibilityOf()` `md-progress-circular` component

Comment: in case 2, option 2, how can we test for `presence` of progress bar when using `*ngIf`? I see the progress bar in the browser but protractor is unable to detect it with `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(loginPage.getProgressBar()), 5000);`